# Confluence Web-Item Plugin Sections

Tags: confluence

I want to place a link in my Confluence help menu.

[image]

In JIRA I simply added a web-item in the section "system.user.options/jira-help" and it worked.
However in Confluence this sections doesn't work.

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/web-ui-modules

It looks like I have to use "system.help" but it won't work too.
"system.user" works fine and others I found like "system.header" work too, so I suppose there is also a scetion-key to place my link at the global help menu which isn't in this documentation. Anybody knows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section I searched for is "system.help/pages".
I found it by accident...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the add-on [Web Fragment Finder](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.wittified.webfragment-finder) to find out that and any other section. Give it a try.

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: This looks really nice, however I found the section, but next time I'll definitely try this plugin. Thanks!